# How to concatenate values from a variable in href attribute of anchor tag using golang

Tags: html, go, url, anchor, href

I have created an API that sends email with a URL in it.

I want to add a parameter in the URL say id, i have saved value in a variable 'id'. So the URL should looks like : "somewebsite/empid=(value of id)"

```
var id = "11221"   // in go

<body>
 <a href = "www.somewebsite.com/empid=(value of id)"> Click here </a>
</body>
```

how can i achieve this??

This is how my mail is being sent :

```
id = "122"
m := gomail.NewMessage()
m.SetHeader("From", "prakashprem.pp2@gmail.com")
m.SetHeader("To", email)
m.SetHeader("Subject", "Paasword Reset for Kibbcom India")
m.SetBody("text/html", "Hi! <br> Please click on <a href = 'https://onboarding.kibbcom.in/forgotpassword?emp=id'>https://onboarding.kibbcom.in/forgotpassword</a>")
```

here i am giving id as static value.

Comment: How is the email body constructed? Is it just plain string initialized in the same scope in which the `id` variable lives. Is it a string initialized in a scope different from that of the `id` variable? Is perhaps loaded from a file? Please provide more information or this question will be closed.

Comment: in go, we have package gomail.v2, i am using that package to set the content type as "text/html" and then sending the mail using gomail.NewDialer() and DialAndSend() functions.

Comment: none of that answers, or is relevant to, how the body of the email is constructed. The code in the question is invalid Go, if you are looking for help, the best way to do that is to provide code that can reproduce the issue.

Comment: The code in the question is not valid Go code, and you still haven't answered a very simple question.

Comment: okay i am adding the code after editing my question.

Comment: editted the question. is it proper now?

Comment: Yes, much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `+` operator to concatenate strings:

```
id = "122"
m := gomail.NewMessage()
m.SetHeader("From", "example@gmail.com")
m.SetHeader("To", email)
m.SetHeader("Subject", "Paasword Reset for Kibbcom India")
m.SetBody("text/html", "Hi! <br> Please click on <a href = 'https://onboarding.kibbcom.in/forgotpassword?emp="+id+"'>https://onboarding.kibbcom.in/forgotpassword</a>")
```

You can also use the `fmt` package to interpolate strings:

```
id = "122"
m := gomail.NewMessage()
m.SetHeader("From", "example@gmail.com")
m.SetHeader("To", email)
m.SetHeader("Subject", "Paasword Reset for Kibbcom India")
m.SetBody("text/html", fmt.Sprintf("Hi! <br> Please click on <a href = 'https://onboarding.kibbcom.in/forgotpassword?emp=%s'>https://onboarding.kibbcom.in/forgotpassword</a>", id))
```

https://play.golang.org/p/BpxJ5XJprmo

Comment: okay, thank you. Once implemented will vote otherwise will update you. Thanks once again and sorry for not posting in correct format. Thanks for that tooo.